# Why opening popover closes select?

Tags: select, sapui5, popover

I was trying to open popover when mouse is over an option of select control
but eachtime when popover opnes the select get closed.

```js
_assignMouseOverPopover: function (select, popover) {
    var items = select.getItems();
    items.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventDelegate({
            onmouseover: this._showHoverPopover.bind(this, popover, element),
            onmouseout: this._hideHoverPopover.bind(this, popover) 
            })
        })
},
_showHoverPopover: function (popover, element, select) {
    this._timeId = setTimeout(() => {
    popover.openBy(element);
    }, 100);            
},
_hideHoverPopover: function (popover){
    clearTimeout(this._timeId) || popover.close();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both popover and dropdown list are rendered with the same id "sap-ui-static". Create a popover and open it; and inspect the html element with a debugger tool. You will see that it is rendered under a DIV element with id "sap-ui-static".

Create a select element and then open the dropdown list; ; and inspect the html element with a debugger tool. You will see that the list is rendered under a DIV element with id "sap-ui-static".

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any way to avoid such a behaviour?

Comment: I cannot think of how to do this because both of them are using the same id. Unless, you are ok with not using dropdown list and use a list control.